# NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I have this problem. I have a operation. But if i want to save?
I want to save all (textfield data picker and result in a label)

I have 2 textfield and 1 datapicker + the result in a Label.

this is my M :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ResultViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myLabel;

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{



    NSDate *past = _data.date ;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                                     initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:unitFlags
                                                        fromDate:past
                                                          toDate:now
                                                        options:0];
    int z = [components day];
    int a = ([_textField1.text intValue]);
    int b = a*([_textField2.text intValue]);

    int r = b * z / 20;

    myLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", r];



}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    NSDate *past = _data.date ;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                                     initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:unitFlags
                                                        fromDate:past
                                                          toDate:now
                                                         options:0];
    int z = [components day];
    int a = ([_textField1.text intValue]);
    int b = a*([_textField2.text intValue]);

    int r = b * z / 20;

    myLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", r];

    self.textField1.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key1"];
    self.textField2.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key2"];
    self.myLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key3"];
    self.data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key4"];


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {

        ResultViewController* destVC = (ResultViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

        destVC.myString = self.myLabel.text;

    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];



    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.textField1.text forKey:@"key1"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.textField2.text forKey:@"key2"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.myLabel.text forKey:@"key3"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.data forKey:@"key4"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

}
@end
```

This code is Right?

Thank you....

Comment: On first glance the code looks right. What specifically is your problem?

Comment: But now my save don't function! I have 3 viewcotroller. I have this operation in 3rd viewcontroller. But if I go to first my date lost. And if i go only in 2nd view controller my date are saving.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things.

- In your `-viewDidLoad`, you call `-synchronize` for some reason. All this does is perform the save function for any events on your user defaults. From what I can see, you don't have any and can skip this call to -synchronize.
- One of your logs is showing the value of 'r'. The value is an int value and you should use '%i' to display this correctly. You are performing some calculations to get that value, so you may want that to be a double or something else, but you are currently casting it to an int.

I don't see anything regarding the user defaults that looks out of sorts. So maybe you can specify what exactly is wrong or isn't being done correctly to get some better help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes code looks right. 
What is your _data variable type?
If you having trouble saving to NSUser. Try to save self.data.date

One tip : You don't need to synchronize after getting values from NSUserdefautls. Use synchronize after setting values to NSUserdefaults.

Comment: But now my save don't function! I have 3 viewcotroller. I have this operation in 3rd viewcontroller. But if I go to first my date lost. And if i go only in 2nd view controller my date are saving.

Comment: and my date in the date picker  don't save...i don't understando what is the problem.